# Support of a relative Cartier divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, curves

For a (smooth, complex) curve $X$, I know that effective Cartier divisors of degree n are represented by $\text{Sym}^n\left(X\right)$. Say I have a relative divisor $D : Z \to \text{Sym}^n\left(X\right)$, I know "Cartier divisors supported on $D$" are also supposed to be representable. My guess is it's $\text{Sym}^n\left(\text{Supp}\left(D\right)\right)$ but I'm not sure how to define the support of a relative divisor. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Where did you read the statement in quotation marks?

Comment: Chiral Algebras by Beilinson and Drinfeld, 3.10.8

Comment: "$D'$ is set-theoretically supported on $D$" should mean that $D'$ is contained in the formal completion of $S \times X$ along $D$. To show that your space is representable, maybe you could construct a closed subscheme $Y \subset Div^{eff}(X) \times Div^{eff}(X)$ parametrizing pairs $(D,D')$ where $D'$ is set-theoretically supported on $D$. The representable space you want is then the fiber of $Y$ at $D$ for the first projection $Y \to Div^{eff}(X)$.